# How to seperate import and export fields in Django-Import-Export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am using [Django-Import-Export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html?highlight=skip_unchanged#import_export.resources.ResourceOptions.skip_diff) and have a model-fields  like below

id, date, val1, val2, val3

what i want is to import by only 2 fields (date and val1)

and i want to export 4 fields (date val1 val2 val3)

if i do like below i can see import fields changing but in export only 2 fields are coming

```
class MyResource(ExportImportObjectHere):
  
    class Meta:
        model = ModelName
        skip_unchanged = True
        fields = ('date', 'val1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `get_import_fields()` and `get_export_fields()`:

```py
class MyResource(ExportImportObjectHere):
    get_import_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_import_fields()
        return [f for f in fields if f.attribute in self._meta.import_fields]

    def get_export_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_export_fields()
        return [f for f in fields if f.attribute in self._meta.export_fields]

    class Meta:
        model = ModelName
        skip_unchanged = True
        fields = ('date', 'val1')

        # these lists declare the attribute name of the model
        import_fields = ('date', 'val1')
        export_fields = ('date', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```